# BCNF decomposition query

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization, decomposition, bcnf

I have a relation **R(A, B, C, D)** with functional dependencies **ABC --> D** and **D --> A**.

The question was, does this have a BCNF, and the answer was as follows:

[image]

> (c) *ABCD* is not in BCNF since *D* --> *A* and *D* is not a key.  However, if we split up *R* as *AD*, *BCD*, we cannot preserve the dependency *ABC* --> *D*. So there is no BCNF decomposition.

Now my question is, I understand that **ABC->D** cannot be preserved if you split the relation **R** into **R1(A,D)** and **R2(BCD)** but what if you changed **R2(BCD)** to **R2(ABCD)**. Wouldn't that preserve it then? Is there any reason we cannot do that?

Comment: Yes, your R2(ABCD) would preserve the FD, but it wouldn't be a decomposition and R1(BCD) would be completely superfluous, wouldn't it?

Comment: My R1 was (A, D) though

Comment: My mistake, but it doesn't affect my argument: the R2(ABCD) is the same relation you started with, so your other relation is superfluous.

Comment: As a side, the fact that a decomposition does not preserve all the FDs does not automatically entails that the decomposition isn't in BCNF: check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCNF#Achievability_of_BCNF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking "So there is no BCNF decomposition" out of context in two ways. There is no (lossless) BCNF decomposition (1) *into relations that are all smaller* (per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)) (2) *that preserves all FDs* (per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1922287/laurids)).

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23966489/3404097):

> [O]ne can always losslessly decompose to 3NF while preserving FDs but
>   BCNF might not preserve them. Nevertheless it's a lossless
>   decomposition: the components, if holding projections of the original,
>   will join to the original. But whenever the original would have had a
>   given value, the components should be projections of it. (If they're
>   not, an error has been made, so we want the DBMS to constrain the
>   components appropriately.) So it is necessary but sufficient to
>   constrain the components to be projections of the original. ABC is
>   trivially so (because it is a key). This leaves us needing to require
>   that AD = ABCD PROJECT {DA}. We say that the components must satisfy
>   that "equality dependency".

You can always non-loss decompose to 5NF. You just might have to add equality dependency constraints if you want to constrain the components per the unpreserved FDs.